# How can I request a URL that is already URL-encoded in python-requests?

Tags: python, utf-8, python-requests, urllib, urlencode

I'm trying to request the following URL:

```
https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/shiraz/barossa-valley-estate-grenache-shiraz-mourv%C3%A8dre-75cl
```

Decoding it with urllib and printing it reveals it to be:

```
In [36]: print urllib.unquote(url)
https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/shiraz/barossa-valley-estate-grenache-shiraz-mourvèdre-75cl
```

i.e. an accented "e".

But it seems no matter what I request with `import requests; requests.get(...)` then I get a 404.

What is the proper input to give to the get method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should decode the url with 'latin-1' after passing it to urrlib unquote

```
>>> 
>>> k = "https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/shiraz/barossa-valley-estate-grenache-shiraz-mourv%C3%A8dre-75cl"
>>> r = requests.get(urllib.unquote(k).decode("latin-1"))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>>
```

Comment: The `decode` is unnecessary and incorrect. It happens to work in this case because è is in Latin-1, but it will fail for any codepoints above U+00FF, like あ. Just do `requests.get(urllib.unquote(k))`.

Comment: please read the op question , he did exactly what you proposed and ended up with 404 not found.
`decode` is necessary and correct to open the link with requests.get .

Comment: Hmmm, you're right in this case...the OP's website seems to expect URLs to be Latin-1 encoded, but that's not the case for other sites.

Comment: Also noticed that `requests.get(urllib.unquote(u'.......'))` works or `requests.get(urllib.unquote(u.decode('utf8')))` or `requests.get(urllib.unquote(u.decode('latin-1')))`, but `requests.get(urllib.unquote(u).decode('utf8'))` does not.